# Custom Responder for jqGrid data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I thought it would be easy.  Define a 'to_grid' Responder module, include it for use in the appropriate places, have jqgrid use urls like '/client.grid' for the interaction, and be able to share rest action with the html responder.  I looked over a selection of jqGrid gems, but didn't see any that were in the sweet spot of recently added code, rails 3.1 compatable, a gem not a plugin, and full REST access.

But evidently I don't understand Responders well enough or it is a wholly inappropriate choice of strategy.

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is a JQuery based data grid that uses JSON to communicate with the server.  My strategy was something like this...

```rb
#Gemfile
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'responder'
gem 'inherited_resources'

#config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :grid

#lib/application_responder.rb
require 'grid_responder'
class ApplicationResponder < ActionController::Responder
  include Responders::GridResponder
end

#lib/grid_responder.rb
module Responders
  module GridResponder
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module InstanceMethods
      def to_grid
        #Only pagination included at this time.
        if get? && resource.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
          total = resource.klass.count
          page, rows = controller.params[:page], controller.params[:rows]
          paginated = resource.page(page).per(rows)
          output = { total: (total / rows) + 1,
                     page: page,
                     records: total,
                     rows: resource }
          render json: output.to_json
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
require "application_responder"
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  self.responder = ApplicationResponder
  respond_to :html, :json, :grid
end

#app/controllers/client_controller.rb
class ClientController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

But calling /client.grid is compaining about no template found.  I truly didn't expect to need a template. And I'm starting to wonder if this strategy is worth pursuing.  I have about a dozen models that I'd need to grid, and it doesn't seem very DRY to do the same thing in 12 different controllers.

**Question**:  Is this strategy worth pursuing or is there an easier or more idiomatic one to try.

**Bonus Question**:  A pointer to working Rest/Responder code I could read and use as a model.

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote the question so that one needs to have knowledge of Ruby on Rails to understand your question. On the other side your main question was about communication with jqGrid. Only the format of the produced JSON input is important for jqGrid. If needed you can add HTTP headers (if RESTfull serveries are also the part of your question). If you would add an example of JSON which produces your Ruby on Rails program that much more people could understand what you want to do and probably gives you some helpful recommendations.

Comment: jqGrid is the consumer of the output from my rails app.  However, my questions is on the rails side and jqGrid is only mentioned as example.  I removed the jqGrid tag.  I understand how the json output is supposed to look, and I can generate it on rails for jqGrid to use.  The problem I'm having is in understanding how to extend ActionController::Responder so that I can automate the json generation and use module code so I follow the principle of DRY.  Right now, for every resource I want to feed to a jqGrid, I need to write code specific to that resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are many potential issues here:

I think this means your conditional is returning false and render is not getting called, so it is looking for a view template to render by default. Did you check to ensure resource.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation) returns true for your use case? Inherited Resources does not return ActiveRecord::Relation for resource - it should return an ActiveRecord::Base instance.

Also, is lib in your autoload path if not you need

```
require Rails.root.join("lib/application_responder")
```

Also, can you confirm that the to_grid method is getting invoked?

I recommend using pry: https://github.com/pry/pry to introspect on what's happening here.